# interactive menu with switch statement

Tags: c, eclipse

Hi I'm trying to make an interactive menu with switch statement in C.
Though I'm unsure of how to trigger a function that has certain arguments.
I'm a total beginner and I'm stumped how to do this.
The function in the switch statement needs the arguments though I would like the function to ask for the numbers. I'm doing this as an assignment and cannot provide the actual code so I made this mock up. Thank you for your help.

Here is an example of code I might use.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMenu()
{
    int choice;

    do
    {
        printf("Main Menu:\n");
        printf("1) do this\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                function(); /* though this needs the arguments */
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 7);

    int main(void)
    {
        printMenu();
        return 0;
    }

    void function(int number1, float number2)
    {
        /*calculation*/
        printf("enter your numbers");
        /* Not sure how to read the numbers in here */
        printf("%d + %d = %d", number1, number2, number1 + number2);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: It would seem you're already using scanf(). Use that again to read in your numbers.

Comment: BTW: note the miss matched float in function's args vs. int/int in its printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `switch` to be as minimal as possible then just call another function which takes in input and then calls the function...

```
case 1:
   read_input_and_function()
   break;

...

void read_input_and_function(void)
{
   printf("Enter your numbers: ");
   /* scanf number1, number2 */
   function(number1, number2);
}
```

Comment: To keep it all in modules how would you kep the switch simple like you've done here and keep all the code in it's fuctions without having to create another function to read the input.  Could  it be done in the "void function" in this example without creating "void read_input_and_function(void)"?

Comment: @GerardGrundy: Not unless you change `void function(int number1, float number2)` to `void function(void)` and prompt for input inside that function.

Answer (score 1):

> The function in the switch statement needs the arguments though I
>   would like the function to ask for the numbers.

How about asking the arguments first , and then calling the function. This way the two arguments can be declared once and be used in other functions of the same switch , but be defined according to the chosen case.

```
void function1(int, float);

   void printMenu()
   {

     int choice = 0 , num1 = 0;
     float num2 = 0;

     do
      {
          printf("Main Menu:\n");
          printf("1) do this\n");
          scanf("%d", &choice);

          switch (choice)
          {
              case 1:
                  printf("\nEnter number 1\n");
                  scanf("%d",&num1);
                  printf("\nEnter number 2\n");
                  scanf("%f",&num2);
                  function1(num1,num2);
                  break;
          }
      } while (choice != 7);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering do you know how to do the scan with fgets?

Comment: @GerardGrundy , if you have declared a string (say) `char mystring [100];` , then to scan into mystring , you would use `fgets (mystring , 100 , stdin)` , the 1st parameter is the pointer to your char array , the second is the size of the array , the third parameter is a file pointer , assuming you want it to read from the console , the file pointer is `stdin` , if you want to read from an actual file , do pass the name of that file pointer  here

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Pi 3.14159216

/*  
*small program of how to create a menu
*/

main ()
{
float degree,radians;
int input;
/*degrees to radians */
float degreesToRadians (float deg)
{
return ((Pi * deg) / 180.0);
}

/*radians to degrees*/
float radiansToDegrees (float rad)
{
 return rad * (180 / Pi);
}
void menu ()
{
 printf ("\n");
 printf ("1. degrees\n");
 printf ("2. radians\n");
 printf ("3. quit\n");
do
switch (input) {
case 1:
          printf ("\n");
          printf ("\n");

          printf (" Enter value of degrees: ");
          scanf ("%f", &degree);
          printf ("RADIANS = %f \n\n", degreesToRadians (degree));
          menu (); 
          break;

case 2:
          printf ("\n");
          printf ("\n");

          printf (" Enter value of radians: ");
          scanf ("%f", &radians);
          printf ("DEGREES = %f \n\n", radiansToDegrees (radians));
          menu (); 
          break;
case 3:
          printf (" quiting app \n");
          exit (0);
          break;
default:
      printf ("wrong option\n");
      break;
  }
while (input != 3);
    getchar ();   
   }
 }
menu ();
}
```